# consume a REST API through KeyStoneJS v6

Tags: graphql, keystone

I'm dealing with a bit of a weird use case. I am using KeyStoneJS v6, through which I must interact with a REST API, make "GET" and "POST" requests, and return the data obtained to my NextJS client through my graphql api.
I have found some examples but they use old versions of KeyStone and I can't figure out how to integrate it into my current project.
I can't find references in the official documentation or on the internet, so I would appreciate any hints on how to proceed.
Greetings in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't sound like a weird use case; you need to extend your GraphQL schema with some custom queries or mutations to wrap another API. Doing so lets you build out parts of your GraphQL schema independently of your Keystone lists. You'll need to define the GraphQL types for the output data and, if you have any arguments being passed in, the input types, then write the resolver that calls out to the other API.

Have a look at the [graphQL schema extension](https://keystonejs.com/docs/guides/schema-extension) guide. It describe how to configure Keystone's `extendGraphqlSchema` option. The Keystone 6 repo has a number of example projects demonstrating schema extension using a variety of GraphQL tooling:

- [`graphql-ts`](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/tree/main/examples/extend-graphql-schema-graphql-ts)
- [`graphql-tools`](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/blob/main/examples/extend-graphql-schema-graphql-tools/schema.ts) and the `mergeSchemas()` function
- [Nexus](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/tree/main/examples/extend-graphql-schema-nexus)

The resolvers themselves can be async, of course. You can call out to remote APIs or use the APIs exposed by the Keystone context object to interact with your database.